# Determine all elements of the coset 3+⟨8⟩ in the group ℤ10

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is:

[coset 3+⟨8⟩](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lektf.jpg)
Determine all elements of the coset 3+⟨8⟩ in the group ℤ10. 
Enter your answer as a comma separated list; make sure that each element you enter is ≥0 and <10.

I firstly solved <8>=<8,64,512,4096...> mod 10=<8,4,2,6>
Does the coset 3+<8> simply mean <3+8,3+4,3+2,3+6>=<11,7,5,9>?
Do I take mod 10 next? Is it <1,7,5,9>?

And my one more question is:
Determine all elements of the coset 1⟨51⟩ in the group U(56).

Is the first step finding <51> and then multiply the set <51> by 1 like the above question?

Thank you!

Comment: It's an *additive* group! If you're thinking about it that way, you should first look at $\langle8,16,24, \dotsc\rangle$.

Comment: $\langle3, 1, 9, 7, 5\rangle$

Comment: Do you mean $\langle 8 \rangle = \{ \ldots, -16, -8, 0, 8, 16, 24, \ldots\}$, so that $3 + \langle 8 \rangle = \{ \ldots, -13, -5, 3, 11, 19, 27, \ldots\}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a little confusion in what you have written in your question

$10\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots , -20, -10, 0 , 10 , 20, \ldots \}$. Now $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is the set of (left) cosets of $10\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. So for example $8+10\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots , 8-20, 8-10, 8+0 , 8+10 , 8+20, \ldots \} =\{\ldots , -12, -2, 8 , 18 , 28, \ldots \} $. Now in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ elements are (left) cosets (which are sets of integers). So it is NOT defined how to add a single integer to a coset in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ since individual integers  are not elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. However you can add two cosets together in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ to get another coset in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. For example $(8+10\mathbb{Z})+(3+10\mathbb{Z})$ which is defined to be the coset $(8+3)+10\mathbb{Z}$ which is $11+ 10\mathbb{Z}$. And if you work that set out you will find you get $\{\ldots, -9,1,11, \ldots \}$. (This is the same coset as $1+10\mathbb{Z}$, and in general $(a+10\mathbb{Z})+(b+10\mathbb{Z})=  c+10\mathbb{Z}$ where $c$ is the remainder of $a+b$ modulo 10).

I hope this helps

Comment: I've upload the actual question. When I learnt coset I didn't learn things like adding an integer to a subgroup. I didn't see any example in the textbook either. I'm so confused.

Comment: @Morgan Rogers. You can talk about a coset of $H$ in (a group) $G$. Notice the coset is not an element of the group. On the other hand you can say the coset in (the group) $K$ say. This says the coset is an element of the group $K$ ($K$ has to be a factor group). Now look at the first line of the question. $3+<8>$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. Actually taking $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ as a set of 10 integers with modulo 10, <8> to be the subgroup generated by the element 8 in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, then $3+<8>$ is an element of the factor group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}/<8>$.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers. The problem with the question (which is from a text book) is it says "the coset $3+<8>$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. No matter which definition you use for $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that coset is NOT in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. So the question does not make sense. Hence the reason for checking. It could be a misprint ($3+<10>$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ does make sense).Or they meant to put "the coset $3+<8>$ of $<8>$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, which also does make sense (but is different to the previous question).

Comment: @KevinBowman ? $3 + \langle 8 \rangle$ is a coset (of $\langle 8 \rangle$) in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$. The parenthetical part is clear from context; I cannot see any alternate meaning this could have. (In fact I am much more confused about the question you are answering in this post than I am about the original question being asked; you seem to be adding $8+3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, I completely don't understand how you read that as the question).  I don't mean to carry this on, just explaining my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You have some of the right idea (aside from some small mistakes); you are doing all computations modulo 10. We have that $\langle 8 \rangle$ denotes the (**additive**) subgroup generated by $8$, as a subset 
$$\langle 8 \rangle = \{8,\ 6,\ 4,\ 2,\ 0 \}$$ 
(in this context I would think of this as $\{8, 8+8=6,\ 8+8+8=4,\ \ldots\}$).  Now you are looking at the coset $3 + \langle 8 \rangle$, which consists of all elements of the form $3+a$, where $a$ is an element of $\langle 8 \rangle$.  You also want to reduce these all modulo 10, so you get 
$$3 + \langle 8 \rangle = \{ 1, \ 9,\ 7, \ 5, \ 3\}.$$

Note that you don't want your answer in angle brackets; these suggest that you are forming the subgroup generated by the elements listed inside (in this case your final result is a coset and not a group).

Comment: so for question b), I firstly find <51> = (51, 51x51, 51x51x51, ....) = (51, 25, 43, 9, 11, 1) mod 56, and then multiply this set by 1, which is still (51, 25, 43, 9, 11, 1), and then take modulo 56 of this set, which is still (51, 25, 43, 9, 11, 1)?

Comment: oh, I should not add bracket for the final answer. It should be 51, 25, 43, 9, 11, 1. Is it correct?